# Обьяснить кусок кода, почему он работает хотя по идее не должен

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

Сделал мини аналог самого просто калькулятора, и проблема в кнопке `"."(demicial)`, а точнее в ее функции нажатия `demicialPress()`, дело в том что там есть кусок кода

```
if (MemoryNewNumber) {
      localMemoryCurrentNumber = '0.';
      MemoryNewNumber = false;
}
```

и вот когда я нажимаю эту кнопку она работает, хотя `MemoryNewNumber` по умолчанию `false`, те кто знает почему так, не могли бы вы мне объяснить в чем дело.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var numbers = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-number'),
    operations = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-operation'),
    clears = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-clear'),
    display = document.getElementById('display'),
    decimal = document.getElementById('btn-decimal'),
    MemoryCurrentNumber = 0,
    MemoryNewNumber = false,
    MemoryPandingOperation = '';

  function searchCurrentElem(variable, funName) {
    for (var i = 0; i < variable.length; i++) {
      var CurrentElem = variable[i];
      CurrentElem.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        funName(e.target.textContent);
      });
    };
  };
  searchCurrentElem(numbers, numberPress);
  searchCurrentElem(clears, clearPress);
  searchCurrentElem(operations, operationPress);
  decimal.addEventListener('click', decimalPress);

  function decimalPress(cell) {
    var localDecimalMemory = display.value;
    if (MemoryNewNumber) {
      localDecimalMemory = '0.';
      MemoryNewNumber = false;
    } else {
      if (localDecimalMemory.indexOf('.') === -1) {
        localDecimalMemory += '.';
      };
      display.value = localDecimalMemory;
    };
  };

  function numberPress(symbol) {
    if (MemoryNewNumber) {
      display.value = symbol;
      MemoryNewNumber = false;
    } else {
      if (display.value === '0') {
        display.value = symbol;
      } else {
        display.value += symbol;
      };
    };
  };

  function operationPress(op) {
    var localOperationMemory = display.value;
    if (MemoryNewNumber && MemoryPandingOperation !== '=') {
      display.value = MemoryCurrentNumber;
    } else {
      MemoryNewNumber = true;
      if (MemoryPandingOperation === '+') {
        MemoryCurrentNumber += parseFloat(localOperationMemory);
      } else if (MemoryPandingOperation === '-') {
        MemoryCurrentNumber -= parseFloat(localOperationMemory);
      } else if (MemoryPandingOperation === '/') {
        MemoryCurrentNumber /= parseFloat(localOperationMemory);
      } else if (MemoryPandingOperation === '*') {
        MemoryCurrentNumber *= parseFloat(localOperationMemory);
      } else {
        MemoryCurrentNumber = parseFloat(localOperationMemory);
      };
      display.value = MemoryCurrentNumber;
      MemoryPandingOperation = op;
    };
  };

  function clearPress(btnClear) {
    if (btnClear == 'ce') {
      display.value = '0';
    } else if (btnClear == 'c') {
      display.value = '0';
      MemoryCurrentNumber = 0;
      MemoryPandingOperation = '';
    };
  };


};
```

```css
#calc {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 500px;
  height: 700px;
  background-color: pink;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 0.7fr 1fr;
  grid-row-gap: 20px;
}

#display {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 70px;
  display: flex;
  text-align: right;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

#calc_display {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#calc__clock-face {
  display: inherit;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 5px;
  grid-row-gap: 5px;
}

.calc__btn {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 500;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.btn-operation:hover {
  background-color: skyblue;
}

.btn-clear:hover {
  background-color: goldenrod;
}

.btn-number:hover {
  background-color: darkgrey;
}

#btn-decimal:hover {
  background-color: greenyellow;
}

.calc__btn:nth-of-type(10) {
  grid-row-start: 5;
  grid-row-end: 6;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 3;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

.calc__btn:nth-of-type(11) {
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 2;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 2;
}

.calc__btn:nth-of-type(12) {
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 2;
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 3;
}

.calc__btn:nth-of-type(13) {
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 2;
  grid-column-start: 4;
  grid-column-end: 5;
}

.calc__btn:nth-of-type(14) {
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 2;
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-column-end: 4;
}

.calc__btn:nth-of-type(15) {
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-row-end: 3;
  grid-column-start: 4;
  grid-column-end: 5;
}

.calc__btn:nth-of-type(16) {
  grid-row-start: 3;
  grid-row-end: 4;
  grid-column-start: 4;
  grid-column-end: 5;
}

.calc__btn:nth-of-type(17) {
  grid-row-start: 4;
  grid-row-end: 6;
  grid-column-start: 4;
  grid-column-end: 5;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}

.calc__btn:nth-of-type(17):hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="calc">
  <div id="calc_display">
    <input id="display" type="text" name="display" placeholder="0000000000" disabled value="0">
  </div>
  <div id="calc__clock-face">
    <button class="calc__btn btn-number">1</button>
    <button class="calc__btn btn btn-number">2</button>
    <button class="calc__btn btn-number">3</button>
    <button class="calc__btn btn-number">4</button>
    <button class="calc__btn btn-number">5</button>
    <button class="calc__btn btn-number">6</button>
    <button class="calc__btn btn-number">7</button>
    <button class="calc__btn btn-number">8</button>
    <button class="calc__btn btn-number">9</button>
    <button class="calc__btn btn-number">0</button>
    <button class="calc__btn btn-clear" id="ce">ce</button>
    <button class="calc__btn btn-clear" id="c">c</button>
    <button class="calc__btn btn-operation">*</button>
    <button class="calc__btn btn-operation">/</button>
    <button class="calc__btn btn-operation">+</button>
    <button class="calc__btn btn-operation">-</button>
    <button class="calc__btn btn-operation">=</button>
    <button class="calc__btn" id="btn-decimal">.</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Также прилагаю ссылку на CodePen С готовым cacl 
https://codepen.io/Kraken_boon/pen/jvWxBZ

Comment: Что Вас остановило от включения в вопрос также и разметки html?

Comment: @Igor, Желание узнать уровень профессионалов на этом ресурсе!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы же в `else` добавляете точку к текущему значению, если ее там нет.

```
} else {
  if (localDecimalMemory.indexOf('.') === -1) {
    localDecimalMemory += '.';
  };
  display.value = localDecimalMemory;
}
```

Comment: Я не про это спрашивал, про первый If в функции, который ставит 0. если число еще не введено, или нужно поставить дробное число. И как видно оно работает только если MemoryNewNumber = true , так как блок if же, а оно по умолчанию false и все равно работает,и мне не понятно как

Comment: @КирикМялик Вы спрашивали как раз про это. Функция не работает (не меняет `display.value`), именно когда переменная `MemoryNewNumber` имеет значение `true`.

Comment: Функция работает, а else это уже тогда когда нажали число и его нужно сделать дробным, меня интересует If почему он работает когда я нажимаю на .  , перед этим не нажав на числа, если переменная что в блоке if , по умолчанию false. Сразу уточню 
if (MemoryNewNumber) {
      localDecimalMemory = '0.';
      MemoryNewNumber = false;

Вот этот If интересует

Comment: @КирикМялик Медленно перечитайте мой ответ.

Comment: Все понял Спасибо большое, Не сразу заметил в чем дело, спасибо еще раз что обьяснили

Comment: @КирикМялик Пожалуйста. Успехов!